# Associate template to Advanced Custom Fields post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use the advanced custom fields plugin and associate it with a partial (probably not the right word) that I wrote that would display the fields from the custom post type.

How do I associate a php file with the custom post type?

**The objective is to be able to embed the partial in a post.**

Here is my partial: *cta-partial.php*

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: CTA-Partial
*/
?>
<!-- cta markup -->
<!-- if there is an article then load -->
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cta_post_type'
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : 
$query->the_post();?> 
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end the markup so as to allow full-width -->
<div class="article" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('cta_background'); ?>')">
    <div class="custom-background">
        <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 image-container">
            <div class="hide-for-medium">
                <img src="<?php the_field('cta_background'); ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns small-12 medium-6 mobile-style">
            <h1> <?php the_field('cta_title');?></h1>
            <p><?php the_field('cta_text'); ?></p>
            <a href="<?php the_field('button_link');?>"><button><?php the_field('button_label')?></button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-12 medium-12 content-wrapper">
    <!-- continue content loop -->
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

This is the file i'd like to render the php associated with my custom fields post type.

Here is the documentation for ACF: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/
I've been scouring the docs and i'm not sure if it's possible. Thank you for the help so far, still researching.

[image of embedded cta in post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0nn4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that what you want is assigned a page to that file. You can use a archive-template.php type file.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index

Comment: I want to embed this in a post instead of assigning a page to that file that way I don't have to break the post loop.

Comment: This might be a clue for what I'd like to do. I just would like to not have my markup in my post: [shortcode](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/shortcode/)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a post id (or user id, or term, or other field) to an ACF field to retrieve the field located elsewhere. And as a side note, it looks like `WP_Query` is overkill for this. Try this:

```
<?php
  $cta_posts = get_posts( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'cta_post_type'
  ) );
  if( $cta_posts ){
    foreach( $cta_posts as $cta_post ):
    ?>
      <div class="article" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field( 'cta_background', $cta_post->ID ); ?>)">
        ...
      </div>
    <?php
    endforeach;
  }
```

My `posts_per_page` assumes you just want one CTA on the page. And if that's the case, a post type may also be overkill. You may want to look at an [ACF options page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/) instead, put your fields on the options page, and then call them with:

```
<div class="article" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field( 'cta_background', 'option' ); ?>)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have a query in your *cta-partial.php* partial.

If you are using `<?php get_template_part('cta-partial.php'); ?>` assigned variables aren't available in the partial.

If you use `<?php include( locate_template('cta-partial.php') ); ?>` instead, then you do have access to variables assigned from the page or post.

In your partial, you *might* need to adjust your `the_field()` usage to pull in current post id. Like this:

`<?php the_field('cta_background', $page_or_post_id); ?>`

Just setup that `$page_or_post_id` in the original page where you call in the partial.